# Issue with Blur Image in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Sketch 3 and I created a rectangle which I made the opacity 70% and gave it a background blur of 20%. When I add this image to my project and try to use it on Xcode the blur disappears from the image and I am left with something I did not create, a see through image with no blur. What can be possibly going on?

```
func createBlurImageView() {
    guard let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.window!.bounds) else {
        return
    }

    imageView.tag = 1000
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Rectangle136")
    self.window!.addSubview(imageView)
    self.window!.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {() -> Void in
        imageView.alpha = 0.8
    })
}

func removeBlurImageView() {
    guard let imageView = self.window?.viewWithTag(1000) as? UIImageView else {
        print("No good")

        return
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {() -> Void in
        imageView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            // remove when finished fading
            imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly include the relevant code and a screenshot of the output. Otherwise there will likely be a lot of unnecessary guesswork going on. Thank you.

Comment: @rp.beltran just did

Comment: did you add blur to an image externally expecting it to actually blur inside the app?

Comment: @Fonix Yeah i actually did. Kinda new at this and if the image was lured and exported from Sketch 3 the uploaded two Xcode i though it would work???

Comment: nope, since a png cant store that kind of information (and its a realtime process, if the blurring needs to be dynamic), you will need to look into using the [UIVisualEffect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBlurEffect) class if you want to add some kind of blur. i personally havent used it so cant help you with that

Comment: @Fonix thanks for the info!